# prevent audio recording while screen recording in Android apps

Tags: android, security, audio, video, video-capture

I'm developing an secure application where i'm restricting another application to record the moment of my application (like videos).

The think is i had restricted the screen capture (both screenshot and video recording) of my application as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617750/prevent-other-applications-form-capturing-recording-screen/30618030#30618030), but i cant able to restrict the audio of my application's video.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playVideo();
    //callAPI();
}
```

After screen capturing i can't able to see the video (shows black screen) but i can hear the audio.

Please help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code what you tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: In that link they have mentioned about the video only. I can do that. But my  question here is how to prevent voice from recording

Comment: @akhilesh0707 He is not ask about screen capture.. He ask about sound capture

Comment: @RanjithKumar you are correct

Comment: Pls check this answer. I got solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46659636/3879847

Comment: @RanjithKumar but this link is about MIC audio recording not software audio recording.

Answer (score 0):

you must detect first that a **recording** is **started**

you can **achieve** this by **register** display listener

```kotlin
 val displayManager = getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as? DisplayManager
        displayManager?.registerDisplayListener(listener, null)
       

    val listener = object : DisplayManager.DisplayListener {
        override fun onDisplayChanged(displayId: Int) {
            
        }

        override fun onDisplayAdded(displayId: Int) {
            
            // here stop video player 
        }

        override fun onDisplayRemoved(displayId: Int) {
          
        }
    }
```

**FLAG_SECURE** will make screen recording record a blank screen

**Hint**: this way only work if recording starts while activity is in **foreground**

## UPDATE 1

The next *workaround* will work with most of third party recording apps before android 10:

by using **AudioManager** to **mute** mic, as these apps use mic

Comment: worked but under condition screen recording app start recording while your app is running and in foregground, otherwise it has no effect

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. may be it'll work with external recorders what about built in recorders? from which we start recording from top menu?