# Way to completely disable screen recording in flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

Using `FLAG_SECURE`([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958353/15096319)) we can avoid recording screen but it still records audio. 
How can we disable audio recording too?

**Note** 
Audio is records after android 10 and system screen recorder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46659636/10147641 I hope it will help you to get context.

Answer (score 0):

This Package 'flutter_windowmanager: ^0.0.1+1'
you can prevent users from taking screenshots or recording videos of the app.

For more details, you can read this article for disable screen recording - https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/prevent-screenshot-and-video-recording-in-flutter-93839325d66c

You are right, your requirements is to disable audio recording.please read this article it may be help you,

> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html

but in IOS I already do it because there is a flag to check if the screen recording is runnning or not, so when it is running I set the volume to zero and it was useful trick.

Comment: Have you read OPs question? They can already stop videos recording and screenshots. They are worried about audio recording, which this article doesn't mention.

Comment: My answer is updated please read it, and let me know if any queries.

Comment: your answer required additional permission which can create issue while releasing app on stores. Any other solution?